# Import a module from the root

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

In this structure:

```
app
  -companies
     --models.py
     --__init__.py
  -manage.py
  -__init__.py
```

---

**models.py**

```
class Company():
   pass
```

**manage.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app.companies.models import Company

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run() 


ImportError: No module named app.companies.models
```

What is the reason? In the views.py, inside the companies folder, the import works without any problem.

Comment: What Python version? Do you have `__init__.py` files in `app` and `companies`?

Comment: @abarnert python 2.7. And yes I have.

Comment: Edit that information into the question.

Comment: Meanwhile, why have you hidden the `app` package with a variable of the same name? I don't think that's related to your problem, but it's at least confusing. (Unless that's the idiomatic to name things with Flask? But I don't think it is; you don't normally call your app package `app`, you call it `spamneggs` or whatever the app is actually called, right?)

Comment: OK, I've tried to reproduce this and I can't. I created the files specified, added the obvious flask imports to the top of each file, removed the extra spaces in `manage.py`, then ran it with `python2.7 -m app.manage`, and it ran without any errors. So… what's different about your case?

Comment: @abarnert, I run exactly the code above, in a new test environment, and I am getting the same error.

Comment: When I run exactly the edited code about (how are you running it, by the way?), I get `NameError: name 'db' is not defined`.

Comment: @abarnert your error is correct, i forgot to remove db.Model. Anyway I am running python manage.py. In your case apparently everything is working properly.

Comment: "I am running python manage.py" is the problem. Let me write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your code, but with how you're running it:

> I am running python manage.py

For this to work, your working directory must be `app`. The current working directory is automatically added to your `sys.path`. There are two possibilities here, both of them bad:

- The more likely is that the directory containing `app` isn't on `sys.path` at all, so as far as Python is concerned, there is no top-level package named `app`.
- The less likely is that the directory containing `app` is on `sys.path`, as well as `app` itself. In that case, you will confuse the hell out of the importer, because the same file or directory can end up imported as two or more separate objects with different names in `sys.modules`. It's hard to predict exactly what problems that can cause, but it will cause problems.

Either way, the solution is to not run it that way. Instead, run it from one directory up, the directory that `app` is in. Which means you have to run it one of the following ways:

```
python -m app.manage
python app/manage.py
```

Comment: `python -m app.manage` works, but the `python app/manage.py` give me the same error. No module named app.companies.models. thanks